# Regaining vertical rhythm in a page, after an odd number of elements

Tags: css, typography

I'm trying to build a 2 column layout with a consistent vertical rhythm (aligned baselines). The calculations for this are pretty straightforward, and I have them working fine. My question is this:

When two columns of text sit side by side, is it possible to have vertical rhythm maintained (or regained) when the vertical-margins in the columns are not 'whole lines'.

In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/beejamin/PMCXt/ I have an unordered list, where both the list, and the list items have 'half a line' of margin-bottom. When there are an even number of list items, the margins add up to a whole line, and the rhythm is kept (that's good!). When there are an odd number though, the baselines are thrown out, and can't ever join up again (unless I get lucky and another odd-numbered list comes along).

Setting whole-line margins on list items is too much (especially with a long list), and setting no margin is not enough.

Is there any way I can avoid/mitigate this? I won't know the number of lines in advance, and I don't want to use javascript for this (I'm trying to build a generic scheme that I can re-use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so here's a pure CSS solution. It relies on :nth-child and :last-child selectors, so only browsers that support those selectors will do it. That's good enough for me, seeing as it's really just a nice piece of polish. It would be easy enough to apply for older browsers with some javascript, too.

Here's the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/beejamin/DpSzW/

The key is this selector:

```
li:nth-child(odd):last-child { margin-bottom: 1.6em /* One full line */}
```

This adds a full line's margin to the last-child of a list, whenever the last-child is also an odd-numbered child. The full line margin replaces the half-line the item would normally have, and so the vertical rhythm is restored. Basically, it makes any list always take up an whole number of lines.

When a list has an even number of items, the selector does nothing, and everything stays nice.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, as I didn't test in all conditions, but this seems to work.

1. Keep the `line-height` the same.
2. keep the `margins` the same as the `line-height`.
3. keep the `font-size` the same.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/PMCXt/1/

Comment: This is one option, sure - but setting the margins on list items to a whole line is too much - when you have a long list of one-or-two word items, it gets really hard to read, and really long.